# How can I reference instances of other classes, both ways without crashing?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple question that I have trouble finding the answer two.  The code below crash.  From debug it seems to come from a loop, I think it is because I reference the other class in both classes.  Can someone please explain what is going on and if possible show how I can have both classes talk to each other (both ways)?  Any help would be very much appreciated !  Thank you.

> **View Controller One**

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController{

    let doSomething = DoSomething()
    var one = "test"

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        doSomething.functionTwo()
   }
}
```

> **Do Something** This Crash

```
import UIKit

class DoSomething: NSObject {

    let viewControllerOne = ViewControllerOne()

    func functionTwo() -> String{
        var two = viewControllerOne.one
    return two
    }
}
```

> **Do Something** This works

```
import UIKit

class DoSomething: NSObject {


    func functionTwo() -> String{
        let viewControllerOne = ViewControllerOne()

        var two = viewControllerOne.one
    return two
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance the initializer of `DoSomething` has to create a `ViewControllerOne`. Since the initializer of `ViewControllerOne` creates `DoSomething` they loop infinitely.
In the second instance `DoSomething` doesn't create until `functionTwo()` is called, so there is no loop.
You can have them talk to each other for example this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerOne : UIViewController 
{        
    let doSomething = DoSomething()
    var one = "test"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doSomething.viewControllerOne = self      
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        doSomething.functionTwo()
    }
}

class DoSomething: NSObject
{    
    weak var viewControllerOne : ViewControllerOne?

    func functionTwo() -> String
    {
        return viewControllerOne?.one ?? String()
    }
}
```

--

So this is how it works in steps:

1. ViewControllerOne is created, the default initializer is called.
   It calls the initializers for doSomething = DoSomething() and var one = "test" (this is equal to String("test") ).
2. The DoSomething default initializer sets the optional viewControllerOne to nil
3. When the instance of ViewControllerOne is finished loading the viewDidLoad is called. It sets the weak doSomething.viewControllerOne property to itself. This means that:

   - the reference count (used for ARC) is not incremented, it is important because if you ever decided to remove the instance of ViewControllerOne, and the doSomething would hold a strong reference to it, they would never get removed by ARC and you would loose memory
   - the property is referencing the view instance that had the viewDidLoad called - `self` in Swift is similar to `this` in other languages
4. When the `functionTwo` is called, it either returns the value of `one` or if the viewControllerOne is nil it returns an empty String

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful.  It gave me a deeper understanding of optionals.  can you explain how doSomething.viewControllerOne = self works. it seems to "capture" DoSomething() and make it self?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the details, hope this helps. Please mark my answer if it does

Comment: Thank you Krzak for a detailed answer - it actually is very helpful - thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Classes never talk. They are blueprints.

You mean instances of a class that need to communicate. Two ways:
either each instance has a reference to the other instance 
or instances send messages to a third object that act as postmaster. See NSNotification for details how to communicate within apps without knowing the other objects by reference.

Comment: But as I understand i am referencing ViewControllerOne in DoSomething by let viewControllerOne = ViewControllerOne().  Why does it work in the second example and crash in the first.  How can I reference ViewControllerOne() once, and then refer to it later.?

Comment: DoSomething creates upon init an instance of ViewControllerOne. ViewControllerOne creates in his init an instance of DoSomething. Loop forever > crash. Create a third class that will create booth classes and store the references of the classes in the other and vice versa. That way each class can talk to the other.

Comment: Right,so how would you solve this? Can you for example explain what the postmaster is?